# Dropbox API using PHP (via dropPHP) download error

Tags: php, wamp, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently using the sample.php page provided with the code [here](https://github.com/f4bsch/DropPHP).

Now it does create the access token just fine.

It also shows my account info as it should be.

It finds all the file directory's in the "files array" part.

It can upload a test image just fine to dropbox.

It can get all the meta data for current images in my dropbox folder.

**However, I can not seem to download the images from dropbox!**

The error i get once it gets to this code:

```
echo "\r\n\r\n<b>Downloading $file->path:</b>\r\n";
print_r($dropbox->DownloadFile($file, $test_file));
```

Is this below:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DropboxException' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\test\DropboxClient.php on line 634 

( ! ) DropboxException: Could not retrieve meta data from header data: Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Sat, 29 Mar 2014 18:07:54 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: application/json
    [4] => Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    [5] => Connection: keep-alive
    [6] => 
)
 in C:\wamp\www\test\DropboxClient.php on line 634 

Call Stack 

# Time Memory Function Location 

1 0.0016 156816 {main}(  ) ..\sample.php:0 

2 1.0901 343472 DropboxClient->DownloadFile(  ) ..\sample.php:80 

3 1.4278 344872 DropboxClient::getMetaFromHeaders(  ) ..\DropboxClient.php:223
```

I'm not sure where i am needing to check out (either in the code or on the wamp side) in order to correct this issue above?

Any help would be great!

Comment: @smarx.... its not a dup if its not even on the same site....

Comment: Feel free to ignore the string "duplicate" in my comment.

Comment: Some discussion here for anyone else following along: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=113980